# Is there a way to print record without duplicate from a table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a table that have many records and others are duplicated. I want to print all the records out but I don't want the duplicated to echo  more than once.

I have a tried to add break when a record is detected to be duplicate but the iteration stopped their immediately.

This is the sql statement.

```
$query = $this->db->query(select * 
from mytable 
where status = '1' and cityname= 'abuja' and age= '27' 
order by id ASC);

foreach ($query->result_array() as $rowx){ 

echo $rowx['xxx'];

}
```

Comment: `break` ends the loop. Use `continue` to skip the current iteration.

Comment: You could also use `SELECT DISTINCT` in your query to prevent duplicate results.

Comment: the sql has "WHERE" clause, so adding DISTINCT is throwing errors.

"select * from mytable where status = '1' and cityname= 'abuja' and age= '27' order by id ASC"

Comment: They shouldn't conflict. `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ...`

Comment: I don't know whether it's because it's Codeigniter, it is still printing the duplicates.

select distinct * 
from mytable 
where status = '1' and cityname= 'abuja' and age= '27' 
order by id ASC

foreach ($query->result_array() as $rowx){ 

echo rowx['xxx'];

}

It is still showing the duplicates.

Comment: Then they're not really duplicates. There are differences in columns that you're not printing. Change `*` to the list of columns you care about. `SELECT DISTINCT xxx FROM ...`

Comment: If you mean they are not same only on SOME fields, you have select only those fields and aggregate functions on all other.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. Your approach has helped me to solve the issue.

I am grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Use `DISTINCT` Keyword, It will resolve your query.

Answer (score 1):

If it is one time query - just use SELECT DISTINCT on all fields except unique(id), should work. For unique field you can use MIN(id) or similar.

General answer for large tables is like this(for small tables just use distinct and delete all which not captured by select distinct):

1. first you need at least one column NOT duplicated. if you have no such column, you have to add it(for example, id serial)
2. after that you have join table with itself and compare all records like this

   select distinct b.id
   from table_name as a join table_name as b
   on a.id< b.id and a.field1=b.field1 and a.field2=b.field2
   /* all fields which matter except id */
   where b.id is not null

Note, that you need an effective index on id+fieldx where is fieldx is quite unique, usually I use some date. Otherwise join will take too much time.

So it will build pairs got you list of IDs which are duplicates. If you have much more then one duplicate per row it is wise to make reverse, i.e make list of unique IDs.

WARNING: it is absolutely necessary check result before delete manually and not forget to add check a.id < b.id. Otherwise every row will be duplicate of itself. Also before issue that SQL use explain and ensure it IS using index for join.

If your table is really large, you should consider:

1. make SQL in transaction with non-blocking transaction level to not affect other operations
2. make sharding using some field.

Comment: you can't usefully mix MIN(id) and SELECT DISTINCT; you would need to group by all the columns you wanted to consider when looking for duplicates and do min(id)

Comment: Yes, you have change distinct to group by. Sorry. But you usually not need that anyway.

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly from my SQL classes, you can use `DISTINCT` to get the list of your records without duplicate.

A quick google query got me to this website: https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-not-show-duplicates-in-sql/
I think this is what you are looking for.